# net core MVC OAuth with custom attribute in authorization URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make a .net core MVC client application, using oAuth2 to get a token to get access to some protected API's.

The Authorization URL requires the following URL parameters:

- scope
- response_type
- redirect_uri
- client_id
- unit_reference

I know how to set most of them, except for the "unit_reference". It's a custom authorization parameter.

The URL should look like this:
https://auth.test.com/Account/Login?scope=acc&unit_reference=9999&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&client_id=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-fffffffff&state=state_this

This is my code so far in Startup.cs ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "AccessProvider";
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOAuth("AccessProvider", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["AccessProvider:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AccessProvider:ClientSecret"];
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account");
    options.Scope.Add("acc");

    // Missing unit_reference

    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://auth.test.com/Account/Login";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://auth.test.com/Token";

    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

I also want to pass some custom parameters.